# Default constructor parameter values in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, constructor-injection

I’m using MVC3, with the Razor syntax, and am going over an example in the Apress book “Pro ASP.Net MVC 3 Framework” (which is very good).  In it the author has this bit in a  _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        @{Html.RenderAction("Summary", "Cart");}
        <div class="title">SPORTS STORE</div>
     </div>
     <div id="categories">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); }
     </div>
     <div id="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

My question has to do with the CartController class.  I see that it’s passed a Cart object in its constructor, but the code in the _Layout.cshtml snippet above doesn’t appear to pass one in when `RenderAction()` is called?

CartController snippet:

```
public ViewResult Summary(Cart cart) {
    return View(cart);
}
```

When I debug that method a Cart object is in fact passed in, but I don’t see where it’s coming from.  This sample code uses Ninject as a dependency injection container but I can’t find any evidence in the configuration that it knows anything about the Cart class.  Is there a ‘default value’ mechanism in MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Summary` is an action *method*.  It is not a constructor.  Therefore, DI doesn't have anything to do with this.   Instead, what we are seeing is the behavior of the default model binder.   That is to say, the model binder will analyze whatever parameters you declare for your action method and will attempt to populate these arguments with data derived from form or query string parameters and route values.

In your particular scenario, since you are not passing in any route values to your `Html.Action` call, all it's doing is instantiating the `Cart` class -- if you inspect it you will presumably see that it's empty (no properties have been set).

However, if you were to pass route values into your `Action` call, it would populate that object.  For example, if `Cart` contained a property called "Size" of type int, and your action call looked like:

```
@Html.Action("Summary", "Cart", new { Size = 5 })
```

Your `Cart` class would now have its `Size` property set to 5.

(Note also that it's far cleaner to use the `Action` method and not the `RenderAction` method in this case.  As you've seen, `RenderAction` assumes a statement-level call, which requires those ugly enclosing curly braces.  `Action` on the other hand is an expression and *returns* the actual HTML content inline, and thus can be expressed in a more concise fashion.)

Comment: You're right, Summary() isn't a constructor-- my apologies there.  And thank you for the terrific explanation of the default model binder behavior.

Comment: Side-note: Isn't `RenderAction` supposed to be better than `Action` because it renders directly to the output stream (instead of building a lengthy string)?  I guess it's still pretty unimportant ... micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

`Summary` is actually an action method, not a constructor. The data can come from a number of different places:

- Route parameters
- Query String
- Form Variables
- Etc.